# Help me understand this line of proof which concerns a marginal expectations in the presence of independent variables

Tags: probability, proof-explanation, expected-value

The following proof comes from Martin Wainwright's book on High-Dimensional Statistics, page 41 on Lipschitz functions of Gaussian variables.

It first begins by the following lemma:

> Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable. Then for any convex function $\phi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, we have
> \begin{equation}
> \mathbb{E}[\phi(f(X)-\mathbb{E}[f(X)])]\leq\mathbb{E}\left[\phi\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\langle\nabla f(X),Y\rangle\right)\right]
> \end{equation}
> where $Y,X\sim N(0,I_{n})$ are standard multivariate Gaussian, and independent.

It then goes on to show this:

> For any $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$, applying the inequality above to the convex function $t\to\exp(\lambda t)$ yields
> \begin{align}
> \mathbb{E}_X\left[\exp\left(\lambda\{f(X)-\mathbb{E}[f(X)]\}\right)\right]&\leq \mathbb{E}_{X,Y}\left[\exp\left(\frac{\lambda\pi}{2}\langle \nabla f(X),Y \rangle\right)\right]\\
> &=\mathbb{E}_X\left[\exp\left(\frac{\lambda^2\pi^2}{8}\lVert\nabla f(X)\rVert_2^2\right)\right]
> \end{align}
> where we have used the independence of $X$ and $Y$ to first take the expectation over $Y$, and the fact that $\langle Y,\nabla f(X)\rangle$ is a zero-mean Gaussian variable with variance $\lVert \nabla f(x)\rVert_2^2$.

I do not follow the equality in the second line of the most recent lines of the equations. Some clarification here would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $Y \sim N(0, I_n)$ then $cAY \sim N(0, c^2AA^T).$ Use this with $c=\frac{\lambda\pi}{2}, A = \nabla f(x)^T$ and take the expectation over Y in $\mathbb{E}_{X,Y}\left[\exp\left(\frac{\lambda\pi}{2}\langle \nabla f(X),Y \rangle\right)\right].$

You can find the expectation of $\exp\left(cX\right)$ when $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ and plug this in. It simplifies to the equation in the equality.